# Is there a minimum event rate required for Gradient Boosting to work?

Tags: sas, boosting, gradient

I am trying to run gradient boosting in enterprise miner on a dataset which has event rate of about 2% and sample size is about 1m.

It fails to produce any output. Which makes me think, is there a minimum event rate required for the gradient boosting to work?

Comment: Have you tried with a subset of the data - perhaps it's the 1 million records and not the rate.

Comment: well, the 1m records are sample itself out of 24 m records.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to produce output"?  Are you saying the program crashes?  Maybe there are options you're not using?  For example, proc mixed doesn't give you estimates of the betas unless you specify the option.

Comment: I mean, it runs, but able to produce the output only with oversampling. But does that mean, boosting works only if you have a good event rate?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting the "able to produce output" - do you get error messages or something?  Have you tried plain old logistic regression?

Comment: yes, logistic regression works fine. but the lift curve is on the random curve. And variable importance is 0 for all variables.

Comment: Did you make sure the labels are passed correctly? And which evaluation metric? Train on just the first 1000 rows or whatever, with verbose on, to debug your training.

Comment: To answer the question directly, no, I've used boosting with that event rate many times with good results.  This is almost certainly an error in using the software.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Enterprise Miner, so cannot offer any advice on common pitfalls.